# What is difference in performance of std:: set<pair<int,int>> and std::map<int,int>

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set

I want to store large number of pairs (around 10^7 pairs) in some container.The operations I want to perform are only `insert` and `find`.

As we can use `std::set` and `std::map` to store pairs, I want to know which container is better in terms of speed. I searched for similar questions but didn't find answer. so please somebody answer my question......

Comment: If performance if your goal, and those are the only operations you're performing, and you're *not* considering an [**`unordered_map`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), I humbly suggest you reconsider, as it will very likely outperform *either* of the other options.

Comment: If you care about performance, you should be measuring. And think of the extra code that has to be written and maintained to make the set behave like the map.

Comment: A map of what? `map<int, int>`? That container would serve a completely different purpose to `set<pair<int,int>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::pair<int, int>` has operator less what makes difference between the second values, too (so it will be used in `std::set<std::pair<int, int>>`) while `std::map` does nothing with second value. In result it means:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
std::set<std::pair<int, int> > s;
m.insert(std::make_pair(0, 0));
m.insert(std::make_pair(0, 1)); // it won't be inserted as key is duplicated
s.insert(std::make_pair(0, 0));
s.insert(std::make_pair(0, 1)); // it will be inserted
```

Update: In most of the STL implementations `set` and `map` implementations are the same (balanced RB tree, usually `set` and `map` come from same template base class), in your case just the way of using operator less will be the difference.

Comment: True, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change the fact that this doesn't answer the question being asked. And you can use a different comparison criteria for a set.